# Sample laravel project error500

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I just installed composer, nodejs, php, laravel and some other packages on my ubuntu. I tried creating a new project (with Laravel new project) and after that I tried to make it run without any change (php artisan serve). But the result was not what I was waiting for. The page showed server error 500. (http://127.0.0.1:8000) and in the console was that error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

I tried to search it but neither of the results helped me.

Comment: what error shown in storage/logs? and did you already made change on .env to adjusting db setup etc?

Comment: Would also help if you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env`. if you still dont get an error message, then it's your server causing the issue (nginx, apache,...) not laravel

Answer (score 0):

First, set right permissions for your Laravel folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 full_path_of_your_laravel_project
```

then set the laravel storage folder to be writable by running:

```
sudo chmod -R o+w full_path_of_your_laravel_project/storage
```

After doing all of that, make sure you have an `.env` file inside your laravel project then run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: ````ErrorException  : file_get_contents(/home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel-Projects/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
  at /home/dbalaskas/Desktop/Laravel-Projects/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
     92|     {
     93|         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
     94|             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
     95|             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  >  96|             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
     97|         ));}````

Answer (score 0):

permissions for your Laravel Project folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 project_folder
```

the laravel public folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 project_folder/public
```

the laravel storage folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 project_folder/storage
```

Open Your Terminal From Project Folder copy .env.example

```
sudo cp .env.example .env
```

then run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of things which could go wrong. Rather than trying every solution one by one, you should look in the error log or just set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env file. It should show you error in your browser